# How to find latest partition value

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala, bigdata

Is it any way to get the latest partition value from Hive query.

Currently I am using `show partitions table_name` to find list of partitions, and then getting the last value by iterating in java. If it any query for that it would be good to find last partition value.

Even though, we can have another option like DDL Query, it takes time to fetch.
`select max(partitions_field) from table_name`

Comment: What do you mean by latest? Most recently written to, or most recently created?

Comment: Yes. It means most recent. In my case the partition column is the date, so I want to get most recent date from the partition

Answer (score 0):

You can try running a command like this in bash:

```bash
hive -e "show partitions shemaName.tableName;" 2>&1 | grep "partitionColumnName" | head -1
```

I guess You've got an idea of the solution, the only thing you need to make sure of is that partition column values are shown in sorted order, in my case they are, because I use format `yyyy.mm.dd`